# Does java have a memory-saving data structure instead of RangeMap?

Tags: java

I want to find a data structure to replace. RangeMap < Integer,String > Key represents the range of numbers, and value is a value mapped in this range. If you use guava's RangeMap, it will lead to basic types of packing, which takes up too much memory. Is there any data structure that takes up less memory? It would be better if there was a ready-made library.

Comment: Why packing tasks up too much memory?

Comment: @shanfeng 没看明白你说的，可能是我翻译软件翻译的有问题，我想描述的意思是，如果用Range的话，Int会被自动装箱成Integer,Integer要比int多占用很多内存

Comment: I get it. Boxing does increase the memory usage. Generic programming is a trade off between commonality and performance. But in general, auto-boxing should not be the question. Perhaps you can give more details about your requirement.

Comment: @shanfeng 我的原始数据会有100w以上，去给每个列构建1个RangeMap ,Key 是ID的范围，value 是映射的值，大概会占2个多G的内存，所以为了节省内存，我是在搜索的时候构建1个临时的子集，但是这样就会在搜索的时候占用一些时间，所以我想找1个节省内存同时搜索效率高的结构，在初始化的时候创建1个全局的索引。

Comment: @shanfeng 装箱占用内存的差距还是比较大的，单个看不出来多了就看出来了